# Can I import dictionary items with the same values into a list?

Tags: python

I'm importing data from a text file, and then made a dictionary out of that. I'm now trying to make a separate one, with the entries that have the same value only. Is that possible?

Sorry if that's a little confusing! But basically, the text file looks like this:

```
"Andrew", "Present"
"Christine", "Absent"
"Liz", "Present"
"James", "Present"
```

I made it into a dictionary first, so I could group them into keys and values, and now I'm trying to make a list of the people who were 'present' only (I don't want to delete the absent ones, I just want a separate list), and then pick one from that list randomly.

This is what I tried:

```
d = {}
with open('directory.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        name, attendance = line.strip().split(',')
        d[name.strip()] = attendance.strip()

present_list = []
present_list.append({"name": str(d.keys), "attendance": "Present"})

print(random.choice(present_list))
```

When I tried running it, I only get:

```
{'name': '<built-in method keys of dict object at 0x02B26690>', 'attendance': 'Present'}
```

Which part should I change? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: First mistake is that your calling d.keys rather than d.keys(). The .keys accesses the method of dict (Which your statement is telling you '<built-in method....>')

Comment: Can you give us an expected output?

Comment: What part of this is attempting to separate present from absent attendees?

Comment: @KyleJ Oh yeah, I didn't notice! Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: @JArunMani I'm trying to make a list where only the 'present' ones will be included, and then pick a random name out of that

Comment: @ScottHunter err, i guess it thought a filter like "attendance": "Present" would work

Comment: Its easy. Just use after the with block `present_lx = [stu for stu in d if d[stu] == 'Present']` Now use random's choice

Comment: @JArunMani thank you for this! i tried it, and i **didn't** get an error, however, what i got was`{'name': 'dict_keys([\'"Andrew"\', \'"Christine"\', \'"Liz"\', \'"James"\'])', 'attendance': 'Present'}`

Comment: No I meant, replace lines 7 and 8 with the given code

Answer (score 0):

Dict.Keys is a method, not a field. So you must instead do:

`d.keys()`

This returns an array generator: if you want a comma separated list with square brackets, just calling str() on it is ok. If you want a different formatting, consider ','.join(dict.keys()) to do a simple comma separated list with no square brackets.

UPDATE:

You also have no filtering in place, instead I'd try something like this, where you grab the list of statuses and then compile (new code in BOLD):

```
d = {}
with open('directory.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        name, attendance = line.strip().split(',')
        **if name.strip() not in d.keys():
            d[attendance.strip()] = [name.strip()]
        else:
            d[attendance.strip()] = d[attendance.strip()].append(name.strip())**
```

This way you don't need to go through all those intermediate steps, and you will have something like {"present": "Andrew, Liz, James"}

Comment: It doesn't return an array, it returns a generator.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I forgot to include the parentheses. So I tried running it again after putting that in, but I still couldn't get it to filter to the 'Present' ones only. Where should I put that part?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
present_list = [key for key in d if d[key] == "Present"]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding! Unfortunately, I tried it, and got this error `raise IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty sequence') from None
IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence`

Comment: This means the `present_list` is empty. Check if `d` contains the data as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

first, you have to change the way you the read lines than you can have in your initial dict as key the `attendence` :

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

with open('directory.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        name, attendance = line.strip().split(',')
        d[attendance.strip()].append(name.strip())

present_list = d["Present"]

print(random.choice(present_list) if present_list else "All absent")
```